# Android extending EditText

Tags: android, html, android-edittext, extend

It seems EditText can get limited html formatting using Html.fromHtml but when adding an image there's no way to animate it. using an animated gif does not work and an animation list shows only the first frame of the animation.

If it is possible and im just doing something wrong in the process please tell me.

Assuming it's not possible, I'd like to extend EditText and rewrite the part that handles the HTML so I could enable animations.

Sadly I have no idea how to accomplish that, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try to integrate with [this](https://github.com/hotveryspicy/ImageViewGIF)(not sure)

Comment: I answered a similar question once, [find it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632801/how-to-add-animated-emoticon-in-textview-or-edittext-in-android/8632889#8632889). Although I managed to get a proof of concept to work, it's far from ideal. However, you might be able to get some useful information/ideas from my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Create your own subclass of `ReplacementSpan`, based off of `DynamicDrawableSpan` and `ImageSpan`, that handles the case where the `Drawable` is an `AnimationDrawable` and starts the animation.

Step #2: Take the `Spanned` object you get back from `fromHtml()` and convert all occurrences of `ImageSpan` to be occurrences of your custom span class from step #1, by finding the existing `ImageSpan` objects (`getSpans()`), removing them (`removeSpan()`), and adding in your replacement (`setSpan()`).

Step #3: Pray that it works and is not a massive performance hog.

Comment: I'm not sure how do do step #1. after creating ReplacmentSpan do I need to override the draw() function? or getDrawable() ?

Comment: @aviran: Try the code from the link in MH's comment on your question. Personally, I have never tried creating my own `DynamicDrawableSpan`, and so I do not know all of the details.