# Use GIF image in ImageSpan with a EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, gif

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8632889/4359492) answer to make my ImageSpan drawable move, but nothing so far. If I use an TextView it works absolutely perfect, but when using EditText the image changes on each type. I know that EditText extends TextView so it should work. What am I missing?

Comment: move? how can `ImageSpan` move?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/long1EU/GifTest) is the whole code and here are the videos: [TextView](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2vkg1nEXylkNm9BbWs0Vm0yVTg) & [EditText](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2vkg1nEXylkSjAtWXNJQXRTbW8)

Comment: I have tried your code with compileSdkVersion 23 and jdk 1.7  and it work fine, the gif display inside Edittext and it animated independent with typing  , so I suggest you to downgrade to lower version and tried to find out the problem.

Comment: @thinh.lam I tried it but still no result. Can you please upload a video to demonstrate that it works on your side?

Comment: here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Ul3SizLn34UmZPVDhnMXFJZlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: thank you, I will try again. SDK 23 and JDK 1.7?

Comment: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_80-b15: Java 1.8 or later is required.